# Why should the client and server have same certificate chain

Tags: security, ssl, wcf-security

I am going through an enterprise application code. It has mutual authentication between client and the server based on certificates.

It mandates that the client and server have the same certificate chain, both the root and the intermediate CAs.

What security benefit does this provide ?

Can it not suffice if we mandate that the root certificate must be trusted on the machine ?

Thanks,
Vivekanand

Answer (score 0):

If both the certs are signed by the root ca and you trust the root ca, then you do not.

However, if either of them is signed by the intermediate ca, then you will need to trust the intermediate ca in addition to the root ca.

In your example you have mentioned only two exchange points (server/client). In an enterprise, the server might be interacting with quite a few other servers, some of which might be signed by an intermediate ca. That could explain the reasoning behind trusting the intermediate cert.

Wikipedia provides a pretty good example about how the chain works
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_certificate_authorities

Answer (score 0):

> It mandates that the client and server have the same certificate chain

No it doesn't. Where did you get that idea? The peers have to have enough of the others' certificate chain to verify them, but their own certificates don't have to be from the same chain as the peer's.